# Ansible: how to get output of shell script command on stdout?

Tags: ansible

I create this simple script which adjust timezone on all machines, called date.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Exit at first error

set -e

# Set the localtime
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Zurich

# Check date
date
```

I run it with ansible

```
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  become_user: root
  tasks:
     - name: Transfer the script
       copy: src=date.sh dest=/tmp/date.sh mode=0700

     - name: Execute the script
       command: sh /tmp/date.sh
```

Works, but how to see output on stdout?
I have tried this, but give me error.

```
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  become_user: root
  tasks:
     - name: Transfer the script
       copy: src=date.sh dest=/tmp/date.sh mode=0700

     - name: Execute the script
       command: sh /tmp/date.sh

  debug:
    msg: "{{ test.stdout.split('\n') }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider just using the [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) which will do the copy and execution for you.

After that you need to use the task argument `register` to store the results into a variable. Once the results are stored you can display it with a `debug` task.

```
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - script: date.sh
    register: results
  - debug:
      var: results.stdout
```

P.S.  There is a [timezone module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/timezone_module.html).  So you could use that and not have to use a script at all.